# React-Native - no header on one of the screen (Stack + Drawer Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My navigation file is as follows. All the screens that are registered with the Stack navigator have a header. The one screen that is registered as the second option with the Drawer navigator has no header at all (OrdersScreen). I tried adding its entry under the Stack navigator as well but it didn't change anything. The setOptions in the OrderScreen have no effect as no header is displayed.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import { Platform } from 'react-native';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

import ProductsOverviewScreen from "../screens/shop/ProductsOverviewScreen";
import ProductDetailScreen from "../screens/shop/ProductDetailScreen";
import CartScreen from "../screens/shop/CartScreen";
import OrdersScreen from "../screens/shop/OrdersScreen";


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


const AppNavigation = () => {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="ShopNavigation">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Products" component={ShopNavigation}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const ShopNavigation = () => {
  return(
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Products"
          component={ProductsOverviewScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'All Products',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary : ''
            },
            headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold'
            },
            headerBackTitleStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'open-sans'
            }
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Product Details" component={ProductDetailScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={CartScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppNavigation;
```

The OrderScreen is as follows:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {FlatList, View, Platform, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {HeaderButtons, Item} from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import CustomHeaderButton from "../../components/UI/HeaderButton";

const OrdersScreen = (props) => {
  const orders = useSelector(state => state.orders.orders);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'Your Orders',
      headerLeft: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="Orders"
            iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-menu' : 'ios-menu'}
            onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
        ),
    });
  },[])


  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Orders screens</Text>
      <Text>some text</Text>
      <Text>Yet another</Text>
      <Button title="toggle Drawer" onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
    </View>
  );
};


export default OrdersScreen;
```

The ProductsOverviewScreen, which is the default screen on the Stack navigation works fine with the header button and the header icons.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import ProductItem from "../../components/ProductItem";
import { addToCart } from "../../redux/cartSlice";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import CustomHeaderButton from "../../components/UI/HeaderButton";

const ProductsOverviewScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const products = useSelector(state => state.products.availableProducts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="Orders"
            iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-menu' : 'ios-menu'}
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="Cart"
            iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-cart' : 'ios-cart'}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      )
      });
    }, [])


  return(
    <FlatList
      data={products}
      renderItem={({item}) =>
        <ProductItem
          image={item.imageUrl}
          title={item.title}
          price={item.price}
          onViewDetail={() => { navigation.navigate('Product Details', { productId: item.id, productTitle: item.title  })}}
          onAddToCart={() => dispatch(addToCart(item))}
        />
      }
      />
  );
};



export default ProductsOverviewScreen;
```

**EDIT:** Thanks. I've done as you said (only one item in the Drawer Navigator and moved OrdersScreen to the StackNavigator. I've added a custom content to the Drawer, as well. The only thing that does not work now is when I open the Drawer from the OrdersScreen (that is accessed through Drawer Custom Content), when I click on 'Products' (default and only Drawer item), nothing happens (The drawer hides but remains on the OrdersScreen). Here's the updated Navigation file

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList, DrawerItem, } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import { Platform } from 'react-native';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

import ProductsOverviewScreen from "../screens/shop/ProductsOverviewScreen";
import ProductDetailScreen from "../screens/shop/ProductDetailScreen";
import CartScreen from "../screens/shop/CartScreen";
import OrdersScreen from "../screens/shop/OrdersScreen";


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="Orders" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Orders')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}



const AppNavigation = () => {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="ShopNavigation" drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Products" component={ShopNavigation}/>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const ShopNavigation = () => {
  return(
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Products"
          component={ProductsOverviewScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'All Products',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary : ''
            },
            headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold'
            },
            headerBackTitleStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'open-sans'
            }
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Product Details" component={ProductDetailScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={CartScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppNavigation;
```

**EDIT2:**
So now I've got two DrawItems in the CustomDrawer and they work fine from both 'All Products' and 'Orders'. The issue I'm having is that I cannot get rid of the default DrawerNavigation entry (not custom content):

```
<Drawer.Screen name="ShopNavigation" component={ShopNavigation}/>
```

as that would mean that Drawer.Navigator does not have any children. By default it has to default to the StackNavigator, doesn't it? You suggested that I should have all the entries coming from CustomDrawerContent. At the moment, the drawer has the following items:

- ShopNavigation (default, does not work, when clicked from 'Orders'.)
- All Products (customcontent, works fine everywhere)
- Orders (Custom content, works fine everywhere)

```html
const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="All Products" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('All Products')} />
      <DrawerItem label="Orders" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Orders')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}



const AppNavigation = () => {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="ShopNavigation" component={ShopNavigation}/>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const ShopNavigation = () => {
  return(
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="All Products"
          component={ProductsOverviewScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'All Products',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary : ''
            },
            headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold'
            },
            headerBackTitleStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'open-sans'
            }
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Product Details" component={ProductDetailScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={CartScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={OrdersScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the header is added to screens within a stack navigator, not to screens that are part of a drawer navigator. If you want the header to be displayed on all screens I recomend that your drawer navigator has only one screen that is actually a stack navigator and that will work. In this case you would also need a custom drawer component to display the items you want since the default will only have one entry.

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, that happens because that default item is created by drawer navigator and redirecting to it's child. But in this case it's child is not the screen, it's the navigator. So you navigate to the navigator, but inside the navigator another screen is being displayed. You have to create custom entries for each item you want on the drawer

Comment: Thanks - I've added another custom item but I don't seem to be able to remove the default/initial drawer screen. It can't be empty, can it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that last part. Could you navigate back to 'Products' screen? Also I just saw that the stack navigator and the products screen have the same name in their respective navigators. That can be an issue. Change them so they have different names.

Comment: Thanks. I"ve changed the name. See my EDIT2. The problem is that you suggested creating custom items for all drawer items. Don't you have to have at least one default 'normal', not custom Drawer.Screen element inside Drawer.Navigator? See my EDIT2.

Comment: No, you don't need to have any default items. You can customize completely the content of drawerContent, so go ahead and remove DrawerItemList. And about the Drawer.Screen element, you are right, you can't remove it, but what you are doing now is exactly what I proposed: you set the stack navigator as the component inside Drawer.Screen. If you remove DrawerItemList from drawerContent you should have everything working as you wanted

Comment: Thank you. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

To control the visibility of header in different screen of drawer navigator, you can use screenOptions to hide and show the header to particular drawer screen.

```
<Drawer.Navigator   screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                        headerShown: route.name === "screen1" ?false : true
                    })}>
```